# How to make standard app store link on top of mobile webpage similar to other sites like youtube

Tags: mobile-safari

When you browse to sites like youtube, decide, and many others on your iphone's safari, their mobile web show a link to their app on the top of the page with x button to close and status of app (like if it's already installed to have open button instead of install).

This looks pretty standard to many sites.  Is there a script of these code that I can copy for my mobile site link to app?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you already tried? More people will be able to help you if you show some research effort. Please see how to ask a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 21):

You just need to add this meta tag (with the relevant details filled in accordingly) to the head of the page on your mobile site that you want it to show up on:

`<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">`

Apple's Developer site has documentation on it http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

Note that this is an iOS6+ feature though.

Comment: something similar for android ?

Comment: ok got it -
http://www.adianteapps.com/blog/article/smart-app-banners-promote-your-app-in-web